Format number to decimal in php
I am sending data by api with json response where it has amount filed.
it is required that amount should be decimal with 2 zeros after the point like this 400.00 and it should not be a string.
I am using laravel framework in php.
I tried to do it with number_format function in php,
with making the string to float(returns 400),
tried using php-decimal libriary, installed php-decimal/php-decimal the output is "400.00" (string)
$amount = "400";
$decimalAmount = new Decimal($amount);
$formattedAmount = $decimalAmount->toFixed(2);

Response is this
    receivingAmount: {
        amount: "400.00"
    }

but I need it to be like this
    receivingAmount: {
        amount: 400.00
    }

Used Brick\Math\BigDecimal Library in laravel, it also returns "400.00" (string)
  $amount = '400';
  $decimalAmount = BigDecimal::of($amount);
  $formattedAmount = $decimalAmount->toScale(2);

Is there any other solution for this case?

There is no floating point implementation, JSON or otherwise, that can preserve trailing zeroes, and either you've misread the spec, or whoever produced the spec needs to be made aware of the lack of sanity of this requirement.

Nothing in the JSON specification seems to disallow trailing zeroes after decimal point, but it's an unusual scenario and few JSON consumers are likely to support it; PHP builtin JSON functions certainly don't.
Also, your code doesn't work because PHP does not have a numeric data type that can handle trailing zeroes.
You'll need to do some string manipulation. One possible way to do it is to come up with some place-holder syntax:
<?php

$data = [
    'receivingAmount' => [
        'amount' => '{{amount:1}}',
    ],
];

$jsonTemplate = json_encode($data, flags: JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
$finalJson = strtr(
    $jsonTemplate,
    [
        '"{{amount:1}}"' => '400.00',
    ]
);
echo $finalJson, PHP_EOL;

{"receivingAmount":{"amount":400.00}}

Last but not least, ensure you're generating this JSON yourself and submitting it as string. If you let Laravel generate it automatically, it will not work.
P.S. Double-check first that you aren't misreading the API specifications.
